# How to bulk redirect in htaccess from old site with parameters

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect

I'm currently updating an old website, but I don't know much about htaccess redirects. I made a script to get all the pages of the website and here are some examples:

For pages:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?p=1 https://www.example.com/page_slug/
```

For categories I did the same:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?c=1 https://www.example.com/cat_slug/
```

Now for the product pages. There are some products that are in multiple categories. For example product 1 is visible in category 1 and 2:

```
index.php?c=1&pr=1
index.php?c=2&pr=1
```

Those products have a canonical to

```
index.php?pr=1
```

For SEO purposes, should I redirect from c=1 and c=2 and from the url without c in it to `https://www.example.com/product/product_slug/`? Or should I just redirect from `index.php?pr=1` to the new page?

If I have to redirect from all the categories, is there a way to write it without having to write every category for the same product (it's written with a script, so it's not that much work, but there will be a lot of lines in the htaccess file)?

Code already in the file (in an update folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /update/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /update/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @MrWhite  I don't know how I missed your answer.  I could have sworn this had no answers when I closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For categories I did the same:
>
> ```
> Redirect 301 /index.php?c=1 https://www.example.com/cat_slug/
> ```

I'm not sure whether you are implying these redirects work OK? But this cannot possibly work... you can't match the query string with a the `Redirect` directive. You need to use mod_rewrite and a condition that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=1$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /cat_slug/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the original query string from the redirected request, otherwise it is passed through unchanged. (On Apache 2.2 you would need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead.)

And the same for *pages*.

> For SEO purposes, should I redirect from `c=1` and `c=2` and from the URL without `c` in it to `https://www.example.com/product/product_slug/`? Or should I just redirect from `index.php?pr=1` to the new page?

If all variations are indexed and/or being linked to then you need to redirect from all variations. However, you can do all that in a single rule, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(c=[12]&)?pr=1$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /product-page/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

> If I have to redirect from all the categories, is there a way to write it without having to write every category for the same product

You only have what is available in the requested URL. So, if you can determine the target URL simply by looking at the source URL then yes, you can effectively "group" these rules together. However, in the examples you've posted, this is not the case.

Comment: This one almost gives me what I want. I was working with the information I found online, but the redirect did indeed not work. With the rules you gave me, I get this url in the browser: `https://www.example.com/cat_slug/?c=1`. I can't seem to get rid of the ?c=1 part and the `https://www.example.com/cat_slug/` is now broken and gives a 404.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need the `QSD` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive to "discard" the original query string from the redirected request (I'm assuming you're on Apache 2.4+).

Comment: "`https://www.example.com/cat_slug/` is now broken and gives a 404." - How are you _routing_ this URL?

Comment: I altered the original post in the end with what I have already in the file.

Comment: I'm on Apache/2.4.35

Comment: To clarify, all these directives are in the same `.htaccess` file inside the `/update` directory? And where have you placed these directives in relation to your existing directives? They need to go _before_ your front-controller. Presumably `/update` is part of your URL structure and included in these redirects?

Comment: I think I found it. There is a .htaccess file on the root for the working website. In the root I have a folder called /update. There is also a .htaccess file in the update folder. The problem was the first rewriterule: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`. After deleting this one and using the updated code you gave me, it works, so I will mark your answer, because it helped me a lot. Thanks for your help, I was trying half a day to figure this one out.

Comment: Looking at your updated code, you have put the directives in the wrong place. As mentioned above, "they need to go _before_ your front-controller." ie. near the start of your `.htaccess` file, not at the end. You can then add back the directive you have removed - that directive simply helps the front-controller work more efficiently by preventing an unnecessary additional pass through the config file (which would trigger an additional filesystem check).

Comment: At the moment, there is nothing else in this file. Later on, after the update works, everything will move to the root folder, where the rewrite rules will go to the top of the existing .htaccess file and the base will be the root folder. Maybe I'm missing something or I'm not understanding you completely. I'm doing a lot of reading now on the .htaccess file and in whichorder to put everything.